# If..., that/this/it

Tags: pronouns, if

What pronouns should be used to refer to the whole content of a preceding "if" clause? For example, Which pronoun should be used in the sentences below?

> i) If the vase did not fall over, it/this/that means that the earthquake yesterday was not that strong.

> ii) If I don't hear from him by Saturday, I'll take it/that as sign that he is not interested in the proposal.

If more than one pronoun is possible, would you detect any difference in meaning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not sure there would be a rule to the instances where determiners or this, that, or it is used. To answer your question.

i. There is a subtle difference but this may be contextually changeable. Seemingly, using '*it*' implies some deduction, using '*this*' similarly implies deduction although you may find one has more surety than the other. Finally, '*that*' seems to mean the same but again, with decidedly less surety than the previous two pronouns.

ii. Either can be used, the strength of feeling conveyed perhaps stronger in '*it*'. Additionally, it should be '*as a sign*'.